# Mysql sum restult from a query

Tags: mysql, count

I have this table of a database:

```
cou_id | cou_tea_1 | cou_tea_2 | cou tea_3
  1          1           1          2
  2          2           1          1
  3          4           1          1
```

Each course has an id, and cou_tea_1, cou_tea_2, cou tes_3 has the teacher that teaches in the lesson 1 of the course, lesson 2 and lesson 3.
In this example in the course 1 the first lesson was made by the teacher 1, the second by the teacher 1 and the third by the teacher 2.
I need a query that gives me the number of the teacher and the total of the lessons he made, in this example:

```
teacher | total_lesson_number
  1              6
  2              2
  4              1
```

Comment: what is the status of this question? if one of the answers solved it, consider accepting an answer by ticking the checkmark next to an answer till it turns green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very poor table design.  In general, when you have multiple columns with the same name, you are storing values in columns.  These should be in a row.

What you need to do is unpivot the data and then aggregate:

```
select teacher, count(*) as total_lesson_number
from (select cou_tea_1 as teacher from t union all
      select cou_tea_2 from t union all
      select cou_tea_3 from t union all
      select cou_tea_4 from t
     ) t
group by teacher;
```

After getting this to work, you should study up on junction tables so you know the right way to store such data in a relational database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL` to unpivot the table, then `GROUP BY` the teacher id:

```
SELECT teacher, COUNT(*) AS total_lesson_number
FROM (
  SELECT cou_id, cou_tea_1 AS teacher
  FROM mytable

  UNION ALL

  SELECT cou_id, cou_tea_2 
  FROM mytable

  UNION ALL

  SELECT cou_id, cou tea_3
  FROM mytable) AS t
GROUP BY teacher
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a new idea I did not want to discard...

```
select teacher, sum(n) as total_lesson_number from (
    (select cou_tea_1 as teacher, count (*) as n from course group by cou_tea_1)
  union all
    (select cou_tea_2 as teacher, count (*) as n from course group by cou_tea_2)
  union all
    (select cou_tea_3 as teacher, count (*) as n from course group by cou_tea_3)
)
group by teacher
```